# woocommerce plugin to add database content to product page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

my problem is that i want to build a price comparison site based on woocommerceand that is exactly my problem.
i want to develop a plugin, which makes it possible to post a database entry to my product page.
i tried to add the content with normal sql query with a shortcode, but the content was shown on top of the site.
the content should be loaded by the SKU number.
by adding the php functions with shortcode, the content will be shown on top of the site..

do you have any solutions how i can display custom database content to my product description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to run some custom PHP code to show content by the SKU number or the product description.

## Option #1

What I would recommend is adding to your current  theme (or to a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if the current one might get modified by an update) a file named:

```
wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php
```

with the contents from:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php
```

Then, in between this piece of code, you might add your own:

```
<?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

    <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php _e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku" itemprop="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>

    <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
    <p><?php echo $content_from_database; ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

and it will show right after the SKU number in the product page.

## Option #2

If you're OK with your content appearing before/after the "Product Short Description", a cleaner approach would be to use the [`woocommerce_short_description`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_short_description/) filter.

This way, by writing a function such as this one in a PHP file:

```
function custom_woocommerce_description( $product_post_excerpt ) { 
    $product_post_excerpt = $product_post_excerpt . $content_from_database; // append your content
    return $product_post_excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'custom_woocommerce_description', 10, 1 );
```

you'll get your content appended to the short description of the product.

Does this solve your problem?